# Android Google Plus Get Person With ID

Tags: android, google-plus

In my app I have users sign in with Google Plus to link their app account to G+. I do this so that the user can find friends.

I then store the user's Google Plus ID so that I can query all of the User's stored for those with certain Google+ Ids.

In my app, I want to be able to automatically get the users G+ profile info, without having to show a sign in dialog.

I get the G+ ID like this:

```
Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(
                mGoogleApiClient).getId()
```

Is their any way I can sign-in for the user using later using their G+ ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can not sign-in a user without them seeing a prompt.

Comment: can I stop the user from signing in with certain accounts and limit him to only a certain one?

Comment: You could. It's not a very nice thing to do to users though. You should let them use the account they want.

Comment: That's okay I let the user choose their account at the beginning of the signup. It would be really irritating for the user to have to keep on signing in with their G+ account whenever they log in on another device

Comment: Realistically people don't have to sign-in on new devices very often so don't worry about it.

Comment: How would I get a list of the user's friends from his ID.

Comment: It would be horrible user experience if they did sign in on a new device and had to choose an account to link with when they alreadt did.